# How to run arquillian-jms-mdb?

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I am pretty green at arquillian and have some problem with it.

Could you please try out this (probably great) arquillian example for MDB:s?
https://github.com/mcs/arquillian-jms-mdb

I also downloaded the JBoss 7.2.0 from:
https://www.redpill-linpro.com/products/jboss/downloads-jboss-and-wildfly

I do not think you need any more setup actually, I bet you have a JDK installed already.

How ever, when I build it with mvn clean install, the container seems to start but the test is never executed. I just get:

```
Running com.github.mcs.arquillian.mdb.example.ExampleMDBBadTest
apr 17, 2018 3:20:37 EM org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer startInternal
INFO: Starting container with: ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java", -Xmx768m, -XX:MaxPermSize=384m, -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y, -ea, -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Fredrik\Applications\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final, -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Fredrik\Applications\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\standalone\log\boot.log, -Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/Fredrik/Applications/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties, -Djboss.bundles.dir=C:\Fredrik\Applications\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\bundles, -jar, C:\Fredrik\Applications\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\jboss-modules.jar, -mp, C:\Fredrik\Applications\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules, -jaxpmodule, javax.xml.jaxp-provider, org.jboss.as.standalone, -server-config, standalone-full.xml]
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
```

...nothing more happens.

Second, if I stop it and run again the port 8787 seems to still be in use, I need to kill the process from the task manger after finding out the PID.

I bet the example is great.
What do you think guys, what I'm I doing wrong?

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

The message `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787` means that the JVM is suspended waiting for a debugger to connect to port `8787`. If you take a look at the command which starts the JVM you'll see this system property:

`-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y`

This is what tells the JVM to "suspend" and wait for a connection on `8787`.

This system property is configured in the project's [arquillian.xml](https://github.com/mcs/arquillian-jms-mdb/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml#L10)

Comment: Hello Justin, thanks for your comment! I only got this example to work if I set the value to "n" actually. Best regards Fredrik

Comment: Yes "suspend" has to be set to "n" (which means "no") because currently is set to "y" (which means "yes"). That's why it was stopping - because the command was telling the JVM to suspend. I believe my answer addressed your issue (i.e. the job would stop with `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787`). Please mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with the author himself and he pointed out that I need to run with Java 7, so in my cmd I set:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Fredrik\Applications\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
set M2_HOME=C:\Fredrik\Applications\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
cd C:\dev\git\test\arquillian-jms-mdb-master
```

I also noticed that I needed to add this property in the arquillian.xml

```
<property name="jbossHome">C:\Fredrik\Applications\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final</property>
```

Second I noticed that it seems like I have to set "suspend=n", else it just behave like before, it just stops and "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787"

Third I noticed that I needed to add these lines to the pom, else I got
"Error assembling EJB: META-INF/ejb-jar.xml is required for ejbVersion 2.x"

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please comment if you disagree to my "workarounds" above.

How ever I think this arquillian example is great and helped me a lot!

Best regards
Fredrik